# Azure Search switch index on full reuild

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

We have a requirement to rebuild the azure index without any downtime. Does Azure Search have out of box feature to rebuild an index on secondary index and swap once it's fully build?

The swap should happen without impacting the customer.

Answer (score 0):

It does not have the feature to automatically rebuild and switch in-place.

You would need to rebuild the Index in parallel, and redirect calls to the newly-created Index, as detailed in [How to rebuild an index in Azure Cognitive Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-reindex).

Answer (score 0):

As of recently, index aliases are **in preview** which allow for a kind of "swapping" mechanism.

Steps to rebuild and swap the index:

1. Create an index.
2. Create an alias for the index.

```json
POST /aliases?api-version=2023-10-01-preview
{
    "name": "my-alias",
    "indexes": ["hotel-samples-index"]
}
```

3. Use alias to query against the index.
4. When a recreate is required, simply create a new index (under a different name).
5. Then swap the index by pointing the alias to the newly create

[Announcement](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ai-azure-ai-services-blog/azure-cognitive-search-now-supports-swapping-indexes/ba-p/3563161) from Microsoft

Preview REST API [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/preview-api/create-or-update-alias)